# CentOS 7 shell script interpretor

Tags: shell, shell-script, centos, terminal

I am starting to write a shell script to be run in CentOS 7.  Which interpreter should it call, and what should the shebang line look like?

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

But when I type `cd /bin` and then `ls -al` there are hundreds of subdirectories, none of which are `sh`.  Which one should I use?  The script will run some maven commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, on CentOS 7, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`, which is the shell available by default on most Linux distros.

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4  9 febr. 08:21 /bin/sh -> bash
```

(If the above command returns `No such file or directory`, then you are right, you'd have a problem. You could then run `which sh` to know the correct path)

So in the case you have the same output than me, using `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash` is the same.

As an alternative, you can use this shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. In this case, it will run the first `sh` or `bash` available in your PATH, whatever `sh` is settled in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or anywhere. Though it may be convenient for portability, note that it may have some security issue if you have several executable named `sh` in your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it call whatever interpreter you wish (bash, csh, zsh, sh, perl, or anything).

`#!/bin/sh` is POSIXly-correct and it should run.

What is the output from `ls /bin | grep s`?

Also, you may want to check your file permissions. That killed me when I was writing my first scripts (`chmod +x ./myscript.sh`).

Comment: `ls /bin | grep sh` produced many screens of output, one line of which was `sh`.

Comment: @CodeMed what are the permissions of your script (`ls -la ./myscript.sh`)?